# Append all methods of a class in a list in Python

Tags: python, class, methods

I would like to add all methods of a class to a list so I can use them to call those methods from that list. I have tried 
`inspect.getmembers(class)`, but I don't know how I would use it to call a function or subclass

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you doing that requires calling every method of a class? There may be an easier way of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why do you need to call all the methods in the first place?

Comment: I'm using tkinter to write a simple program which allows you to try out different encryption methods. For every encryption method I also have at least one page explaining how it works. I have a class for each encryption method with several sub-classes, each representing one page in the program. What allows me to switch between the pages is a list containing all the different sub-classes. So for the sake of having shorter and neater code (It will be graded) I would like to know how I could reduce it in such a way that I don't need to have a huge list with way too many sub-classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a class `Abc`:

```
class Abc:
    def user_function(arg):
        print(arg)
```

You can get all it's methods with `dir(Abc)`. By calling it, you will get magic methods as well (`__init__`, `__str__` and so on). So you can filter it like that:

```
methods_names = [method for method in dir(Abc) if not method.startswith('__')]
```

If you want to call it, you can use `getattr`:

```
first_method = getattr(Abc, methods_names[0])
```

Note that `first_method` will expect two arguments: `self` and `arg`, where `self` can be an instance of `Abc` class.
So:

```
instance = Abc()
first_method(instance, 'Hello world')
```